# New entries in nested ViewModel are not recreated on ModelState.Merge()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post-redirect-get

We are using the well known Post-Redirect-Get pattern to prevent double posting in our MVC application. Like most implementations we store the Model-State inside `TempData` in the Http-Post-Action on errors and restore the Model-State with `ModelState.Merge()` inside the action we are redirected to. This works very well in most cases but breaks in the following case where we are adding new elements to a nested View-Model.

1. A editor template on the page is refreshed and contains an additional nested view-model element.
2. In another field on the surrounding view that incorporates the editor template another field is invalid and will prevent the commit into the db and forces the PRG into the error path (redirect to GET).
3. When the page gets submitted the Model-State contains the new nested element  `Property[n+1].Value` and its value and is stored into `TempData`. After the `Merge()` the model-state in `filterContext` of the redirected to Get-Method contains the additional element.

Now when the view gets rendered the new element does not recreate because it is only in the model-state but not in the model. View creation loops over the model (that doesn't have the new nested object) and the `EditorFor<>` gets the value from the model-state which is as expected. Is there a generic solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no quick solution to the problem. We switched from a redirect on the error path in the controller (strict PRG) to a implementation described in this [blog](http://timgthomas.com/2013/09/simplify-client-side-validation-by-adding-a-server/). It works very well and did even speed up the application as the returned json on the controllers error path is handled much faster than a full ViewResult.